# Switching from tab to splitted window in vi/vim?

Tags: vim, vi

We can make new tab using `:tabnew`.
We can split window using `:vs` or `:sp`.

Sometimes I want to switch from tab to splitted window to compare my code or switch back to get more space. Now I do it by closing it then use another command. Is there any easier way?

Thank you.

Comment: Fair question, since there exists a command that is (sort of) the counterpart to what you're asking: `Ctrl-w T` moves the current window to a new tab page.

Answer (score 4):

Tabs and splits are different concepts.

A vim "tab" is really a window layout. It means that for example you can have a tab with vertically split windows and another one with horizontally split windows.

It seems you question is when I have split windows, how do I switch back to a full view. You can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> to expand the current window to the full tab.

See `:help windows.txt` to get the full list of commands related to windows management.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way (with built-in means) to move / copy a window from one location to another (split, tab page) within Vim is to use the current window's *buffer number* (which can be put into the `'statusline'`, or `:ls` will tell you), e.g. as in:

```
:sb[uffer] 3
```

To open the current window in a separate tab, you can use:

```
:tab split
```

Comment: +1, but `sb` will not do what you advertise if e.g. `switchbuf` is set to include `useopen`. Also, you'd require an additional `windo diffthis` to get into diff mode

Answer (score 2):

If you

```
:edit file1
:tabedit file2
```

and then want to compare them, just

```
:vert diffsplit file1
```

Answer (score 2):

switch all buffers to vertical split:

```
:bufdo vs
```

switch all buffers to horizontal split:

```
:bufdo sp
```

switch all buffers to tab mode:

```
:bufdo tab split
```

(use [ctrl]-w o to close all but current window in split mode, :bdel to delete current buffer, :qa to close all / :wqa to save and close all)